# Print form data Autosaved with sisyphus

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosave

I have a form which the user will use to write down notes ( i am using sisyphus.min.js to autosave the form data). When the user wants to print his notes and he clicks print, the data inside the form (i.e. all his notes) should be printed without the constraints of the form borders (i only want to print the user's notes. I have tried the code below but when i click print the form borders and only a portion of the data inside the form appears in the print window. How can I extract all the data inside the form when the user clicks print (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sisyphus.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    @media print
    {
        #non-printable { display: none; }
        #printable{ display: block; }
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="non-printable">

        <h1> Sample Content</h1>

    </div>

    <div id="printable">
        <form action="" id="myform" name="myform" method="post">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="13"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myform').sisyphus();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you believe that cacheing the form data with sisyphus will affect the output when it is printed? It looks to me that sisyphus.js does not affect print ing.

Comment: @Elliott- I don't believe caching the form data with sisyphus will affect the output when it is printed but if you run my code and insert long content in the form and you ctrl+p to print, you will only get the data which fits the form window to print not the whole content inside the form.